# How to dynamically set urls in Django

Tags: django

I have a form that updates the quantity of a product or a custom order, i am currently using
`"{% if custom_orders %}{% url 'custom_order_update' item.custom_order.id %}{% else %}{% url 'update_bag' item.product_id %}{% endif %}"` as the action URL, however Django is complaning with a redirect error for this syntax. Could anyone recommend another way to set the URL dynamically?

urls.py - bag app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_bag, name='view_bag'),
    path('add/<product_id>/', views.add_to_bag, name='add_to_bag'),
    path('update/<product_id>/', views.update_bag, name='update_bag'),
    path('remove/<product_id>/', views.remove_from_bag, name='remove_from_bag'),
]
```

views.py - bag app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse

def view_bag(request):
    """
    A view to return bag page
    """
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
    custom_orders = bag.get('custom_orders', [])

    context = {
        'custom_orders': custom_orders
    }
    return render(request, 'bag/bag.html', context)


def add_to_bag(request, product_id):
    """ Add a quantity of the specified product to the shopping bag """
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    redirect_url = request.POST.get('redirect_url')
    
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    if product_id in list(bag.keys()):
        bag[product_id] += quantity
    else:
        bag[product_id] = quantity

    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(redirect_url)


def update_bag(request, product_id):
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    print(quantity)
            
    if quantity > 0:
        bag[product_id] = quantity
    else:
        bag.pop(product_id, None)
    request.session['bag'] = bag

    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))

def remove_from_bag(request, product_id):
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
    bag.pop(product_id)
    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))
```

urls.py custom_order app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.custom_order, name='custom_order'),
    path('price/<int:custom_order_id>/', views.custom_order_details, name='price'),
    path('add_custom_order/<int:custom_order_id>/', views.add_custom_order_to_bag, name='add_custom_order'),
    path('update_custom_order/<int:custom_order_id>/', views.custom_order_update, name='custom_order_update'),
    path('delete_custom_order/<int:custom_order_id>/', views.custom_order_delete, name='custom_order_delete'),
]
```

views.py custom_order app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404
from .models import CustomOrder
from profiles.models import UserProfile
from .forms import CustomOrderForm
from django.contrib import messages


def custom_order(request):
    """ A view to display custom_order form """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        custom_form = CustomOrderForm(request.POST)
        if custom_form.is_valid():
            custom = custom_form.save(commit=False)
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            custom.user_profile = user_profile
            custom.save()
            custom_order_id = custom.pk
            messages.success(request, f'Your custom order has been added to your bag. Price: Eur{custom.price}')
            return redirect(reverse('price', args=[custom_order_id]))
    else:
        custom_form = CustomOrderForm()

    context = {
        'custom_form': custom_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'custom_order/custom_order.html', context)

 
def custom_order_details(request, custom_order_id):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    custom_order = CustomOrder.objects.get(pk=custom_order_id, user_profile=user_profile)
    price = custom_order.price
    context = {
        'price': price,
        'custom_order': custom_order,
        'custom_order.id': custom_order_id
    }

    return render(request, 'custom_order/custom_order_price.html', context)

def add_custom_order_to_bag(request, custom_order_id):
    """Add custom order to the shopping bag """
    custom_order = CustomOrder.objects.get(pk=custom_order_id)
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    if 'custom_orders' not in bag:
        bag['custom_orders'] = []

    bag['custom_orders'].append(custom_order_id)
   
    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))


def custom_order_update(request, custom_order_id):
    """ Updates the quantity of custom orders added to the bag"""
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    custom_orders = bag.get('custom_orders', [])
    found = False
    
    for quantity_dict in custom_orders:
        if isinstance(quantity_dict, dict) and str(custom_order_id) in quantity_dict:
            quantity_dict[str(custom_order_id)] = quantity
            found = True
            break
    
    if not found:
        custom_orders.append({str(custom_order_id): quantity})
        custom_orders.remove(custom_order_id)


    bag['custom_orders'] = custom_orders

    request.session['bag'] = bag

    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))

def custom_order_delete(request, custom_order_id):
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
    custom_orders = bag.get('custom_orders', [])
    for quantity_dict in custom_orders:
        if isinstance(quantity_dict, dict) and str(custom_order_id) in quantity_dict:
            custom_orders.remove(quantity_dict)
        else:
            custom_orders.remove(custom_order_id)
    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))
```

Comment: can you share your URL.py and Views?

Comment: I have edited with my URLs and views for each app. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [URL namespaces <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) from now on so that even if different applications use the same URL names, these can still be resolved.

We will now add an app name to all our app URLConfig files so that we can use URL namespaces. For example in `bag_app.urls`.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "bag_app"

urlpatterns = [
    # ••• Same as before •••
]
```

We will then `include` URLConfig modules from your different apps into your root URLConfig module.

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("root-url-for-bag_app", include("bag_app.urls"))
    # ••• Include the rest here •••
]
```

So now the code in the template should use URL namespaces as follows:

```
{% if custom_orders %}
    {% url 'custom_order_app:custom_order_update' item.custom_order.id %} # [1]
{% else %}
    {% url 'bag_app:update_bag' item.product_id %}
{% endif %}
```

And your `redirect`s should take [`reverse`d namespaced URLs. <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#id5)

```
redirect(reverse('bag_app:view_bag'))
```

---

<sub>[1] Like we did in `bag_app`, you should add an app name to `custom_order_app`‘s URLConfig and `include` this in the root URLConfig module.</sub>